# Traefik 'PathPrefix' not working as expected

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have a kube service that has a `/customers` resource that will return all customers. It can also return a specific customer at `/customers/1`. I've configured Traefik ingress as follows:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefix
  name: customerd
  namespace: video
spec:
  rules:
  - host: custd.kube
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: customerd
          servicePort: http
        path: /customers
      - backend:
          serviceName: customerd
          servicePort: http
        path: /custdhealth
      - backend:
          serviceName: customerd
          servicePort: http
        path: /metrics
      - backend:
          serviceName: customerd
          servicePort: http
        path: /sleeper
```

Note that the following annotation is present: `traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefix`. From the Traefik documentation:

> Use a * Prefix * matcher if your backend listens on a particular base
>   path but also serves requests on sub-paths. For instance, PathPrefix:
>   /products would match /products but also /products/shoes and
>   /products/shirts. Since the path is forwarded as-is, your backend is
>   expected to listen on /products.

The issue is that when I submit a request to `/customers/1` the response is a 404. I've confirmed that the request doesn't reach the service. If I change `PathPrefix` to `PathPrefixStrip` requests to `/customers` return a 404, as expected, since the service isn't listening on `/`. So it seems like I'm using the annotation correctly.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or further troubleshooting steps?

Comment: Are you using Traefik 2.0?

Comment: No, Traefik 1.7. Sorry for not including that detail. Kubernetes server version 1.15.3, client 1.17.3.

Answer (score 4):

After more debugging I figured out the problem. It wasn’t with how I was using Traefik, it was a misunderstanding on my part about how Golang HTTP routing works. My route was coded as “/customers”. Turns out this route will never satisfy “/customers/{id}”. “/customers/“ however will route both “/customers” and “/customers/{id}”. So after a simple code change it all worked.

One factor complicating my debugging efforts was this behavior isn’t visible by inspecting the (non-Golang library) code or putting in debug log messages.